# What is the difference between write and flash

Tags: stm32, bootloader

My apologies for my very naive question.

I am trying to get some understanding of the STM32 bootloader,
specifically I am looking at [stm32flash](https://code.google.com/p/stm32flash/)
where I read:

> - write to flash/ram
> - read from flash/ram
> - flash from binary file
> - save flash to binary file

Please I do not understand what is the difference between

> - write to flash/ram

and

> - flash from binary file

---

And what is the difference between:

> - read from flash/ram

and

> - save flash to binary file

Thanks!

LISA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Write** and **flash** are not comparable. The former is a "action", but the latter is a "noun".

**write to flash/ram**: Write something (such as your binary file, but can also be others) to the flash or the RAM, this is so called "programming the flash/RAM" or simply "programming".

**flash from binary file**: Means write your binary file (such as your binary program) to the flash memory. The difference with the first is this designate the source ----- a file.

**read from flash/ram**: Read data from the flash/RAM.

**save flash to binary file**: Has similar meaning, but it designate the target ---- a file.